# Как изменить размер FAB(кнопки плавающего действия) на прямоугольник?

Tags: android

На данный момент FAB это круглая кнопка,как изменить в прямоугольную кнопку и в нее поместить текст "Перейти в корзину"

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/done"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Comment: Так используете обычную кнопку с текстом и всё

Comment: Extended FAB не подойдет? https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button/android#extended-fabs

Comment: Подойдет ,спасибо Eugene Krivenja